# Rails server not starting in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment

I want to start my rails server in production mode but it is exiting immediately.

```
rails server -e production
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.4 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
Exiting
```

Comment: Please share complete error which you can see on console.

Comment: try this RAILS_ENV=production rails server

Comment: and in development? rails s

Comment: I'm guessing you already have a server running on port 3000, no way for us to know without seeing the full error message. try `rails server -e production -p 5000`